# awk: dealing with variable in if statement

Tags: bash, awk, logic

I am trying to understand how `awk` deals with variables in `if` statements.

Here is a toy text file:

```
$ cat myscript.sh 
#! /bin/bash

set -eu
set -o pipefail

IFS=$'\n\t'

for arg in $@; do
    echo "do something with file $arg"
done
```

Now I want `awk` to print the longest line in the file.
I thought of doing that:

```
$  awk '{max = 0}{if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0)} else {}} END {print max}' myscript.sh
```

But this print the length of the last line.
However, when I run the following:

```
awk '{if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0)} else {}}END{print max}' myscript.sh
```

The outcome is correct and it prints the right length `35`.

I cannot really understand why when I specify the `max` variable before the `if` statement, the condition is not recognized.
I am sure there is an easy explanation for the `awk-gurus`, but I personally cannot see it.

Thank you

Comment: `{max = 0}` in first code is setting `max` to zero before every record.

Comment: I did just to use it as a dummy variable, and then I assign to it the next values if `length` if it longer than the previous `max` value. Does this logic hold?

Comment: `awk 'length() > max{max = length()} END{print max}' file` is shorter.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I do not understand, where do I need to define the variable `max`? or there is no need for that?

Comment: No there is no need to define it. If you really want to initialize any variable then put it in `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the first command a little bit to make it work :

```
awk 'BEGIN{max = 0}{if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0)} else {}} END {print max}' myscript.sh
```

This way, you initialize the variable max at the beginning of the script. Without the BEGIN statement, max is being updated to 0 at every row.

However, awk variables have default values that depend on the context. You can read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) to understand the logic behind.

> Variables in awk can be assigned either numeric or string values. The kind of value a variable holds can change over the life of a program. By default, variables are initialized to the empty string, which is zero if converted to a number.

With this command :

```
awk '{if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0)} else {}}END{print max}' myscript.sh
```

Awk will initialize max to 0 at the first row because you are comparing it to length($0) which is an integer.

Comment: wrt `Awk will initialize max to 0 at the first row because you are comparing it to length($0) which is an integer.` - no it won't. If it did then running that command on an empty file would output `0` but it'll output a null string instead. When `length($0) > max` is first executed `max` is of type numeric-string with a value of zero-or-null, it's the **comparison** that's treated as numeric since it's comparing a number to a numeric sting, but `max` doesn't change it's type or value at that point.

Comment: Try running these commands to see it: `seq 2 | awk '{print "max=" ( (max == 0) && (max == "") ? "zero-or-null" : max ); max=0}'` and `seq 2 | awk '{print "max=" ( (max == 0) && (max == "") ? "zero-or-null" : max ); max=""}'`. In gawk you can actually just print `typeof(max)` to see it's type at any point, e.g. `echo "" | awk '{if (length($0) > max) {max = length($0)} print typeof(max)}'` will output `unassigned`.

Answer (score 0):

@Corentin already explained your problem so you should leave his/her answer as accepted but just FYI the right way to print the length of the longest line in the file is this:

```
awk '{cur=length()} cur>max{max=cur} END{print max+0}' myscript.sh
```

That ensures max will be a number even if all lines are empty, doesn't call length() multiple times per line, and ensures you'll get numeric output even if the input is empty (just like `wc` does for empty files).